# Bind datagridview from bindingsource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 1 datagridview. I want to bind datagridview based on textbox character without entering in textbox. Also I want to enable and disable gridview.

This my code which I have tried:

```
void txtPartyState_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.dgvState.Visible = true;
        this.txtPartyCity.Visible = false;
        this.dgvState.Location = new Point(140, 110);
        this.dgvState.Focus();
        this.txtPartyState.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void txtPartyState_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bs.Filter = string.Format("State LIKE '{0}%'", txtPartyState.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you binding the DataSource to DataGridView?

Comment: public void bindStateGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                string query = @"select * from StateMaster";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                bs.DataSource = dt;
                this.dgvState.DataSource = bs;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

Comment: on form load event

Comment: Update your code where you have written it. And what do you mean by without entering in textbox ?

Comment: In txtPartyState_TextChanged; you are changing the query which essentially change the data in DataSet. Have you updated the datasource post that? And in case of web app, binding it again.

Comment: when got focus on txtPartyState there is open state gridview and directly goes to focus on it...now i want to filter on grid view by press any keyword without focus on txtPartyState